# Tricky javascript question i got asked in interview today

Tags: javascript

> say you have "n number of kids sitting in a circle"
>      and "k" toys available to distribute 
>      and "i" is the position to start from.
>   print the last kid who gets the toy

and my answer was

```
// n=5, k=3, i=1 // result 3

function get_last_kid(n,k,i)
{
  if(i==1)
  {
    return (k%n); //returns (toys/number of kids)
  }
  else
  {
    return (k%n)+i;
  }
}

alert( get_last_kid(3,7,3) )
```

Tho it gives out the answer for some scenarios, but the answer is still wrong for other scenarios, could someone tell me how should i get by cracking this code.. thank you...

Comment: With 3 kids and 7 toys, they all get one. So what would it return in that case? The last kid who gets the most number of toys? Is `i` zero indexed? Does 0 mean first kid or 1 mean first kid? Also `k` is a terrible choice of variable name for toys when the `n` represents kids.

Comment: Depending on the ways that the toys are distributed, the answer can be different.

Comment: @ThumChoonTat I think its safe to assume they are being handed in turn like `kid1, kid2, kid3, ... kidn` or is it `kid0, kid1, kidn-1`?

Comment: if `k<n` the formula to use is `(n-k)+i` however if `k>=n` use `(k%n)+(i-1)` It helps if you have a pen and paper to draw and visualize.

Comment: @Axois `(n-k)+i` is wrong. `n = 5, k = 3, i = 4` gives you `(5 - 3) + 4 = 2 + 4 = 6`

Comment: @Herohtar oops my bad, I guess i didn't account for it when it overshoots. One simple get around is probably `if (output >= n) {return (output%n) }`

Comment: @Axois There actually isn't any need for logic... it's a basic math formula. `(k+i)%n` should work for all values. It might need some adjustments depending on whether the start index and expected output are zero-based or not, but you should only ever need a single formula.

Comment: @Herohtar Thanks for sharing! I've not encountered these kinds of questions before, so i thought I'd work on it manually with a pen and paper. I didnt actually think it could be solved by such a simple equation!

Comment: Minor correction, I should have written `((k-1)+i)%n)`. Drawing out a representation of the kids and counting using various starting positions and numbers of toys can actually be a good way to help figure out the formula.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var n = 5; // childrend
var k = 8; // toys
var i = 3; // giving starts at



// get the last child to receive the toy if we start from 1st child 
var end = k%n;
// adjust if answer is 0 (there is no 0 position)
if (end == 0) end = n;
console.log(end);

// adjust end base on where the giving starts
var shouldbeend = end + (i - 1);
console.log(shouldbeend);

// adjust end base on the number of children (end can't go beyond the number of childrend)
var actualend = shouldbeend%n;
if (actualend == 0) actualend = n;
console.log(actualend);
```

Comment: why is  "end + (i - 1)" correct , why it can't be "end + i

Comment: could you please explain

Comment: This is much too complex and I'm not sure it's even correct. If the input and output indexes are zero-based `(k+i)%n` should be all you need. If one or the other or both are one-based instead, that will change the formula slightly, but it will still be a single formula. However, you didn't clarify that in your question.

Comment: @Herohtar the above answer is correct and i have tested it, your formula is correct except a small mistake in it (k+ (i-1) )%n) is the correct one and the answer above executes the same formula, except in a step by step way

Comment: You're right, I should have written `((k-1)+i)%n)` (which is equivalent to what you wrote)